# Where do terminal font colors come from in an SSH session?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, colors, solaris

Using gnome-terminal I connect to my servers at work using SSH from Ubuntu 18.04 or 22.04. These work servers can be Sparc Solaris or Linux (Fedora).

When I connect to the Solaris servers from my local terminal, commands like `ls` are not colorized. So, I have setup aliases like `ls --color=auto`. After that the colors are exactly the same as my terminal before SSH.

When I connect to the Fedora Linux servers from my local terminal on the other hand, they are already colorized. I.e.: for commands like `ls` there is already an alias `ls --color=auto` setup. But the color is much darker than my terminal before SSH.

When I connect to my own server running Ubuntu 18.04 from my own terminal they are also colorized, and the colors are the same as in the Ubuntu I connect from.

Now interestingly, when I connect to the Solaris server from the Linux Fedora server the colors are also dark but a different dark.

Colors in my terminal (Ubuntu 18.04) before SSH.
In Solaris SSH session.
And in Ubuntu 18.04 SSH session:

[image]

Colors in Linux Fedora SSH session:

[image]

Solars SSH session from Fedora Linux SSH session:

[image]

Where is the connection to Linux Fedora taking the colors from?
And what about the connection to Solaris?

PS: Because I set it myself the colors in the prompt (PS1) are the same in all connections.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/clicolor-and-ls-colors-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

All of the colors are coming from the machine that you are connecting to.  You would have to set the colors manually to make them the same.  The reason that they are different is because they are different operating systems.

Comment: But Solaris has one set of colors when I connect from my local terminal and a different set of colors when I connect from the Fedora Linux box. In both cases I connect to the same user and the same profile is invoked..

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the different OSes render the colors differently.